# Emacs key-binding to shell command with no output

Tags: emacs, latex

My question may be split into two perhaps? I have a tex file (main.tex) that, through \subfile, calls on a bunch of files in a subfolder. Eg, main.tex:

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\subfile{chapters/introduction}
```

When I edit introduction.tex in emacs, I need to compile main.tex to see it. I'd like to have a shortcut key so that, whilst editing introduction.tex, it can call "pdflatex main.tex" and then suppress the output so it doesn't open up in a minibuffer.

Comment: The following link contains examples for using latexmk on OSX (*without* AUCTeX); on Windows (*without* AUCTeX); and on both of the aforementioned operating systems using the AUCTeX package (that would need to be installed, if not already installed).  You can modify the commands to use pdflatex instead of latexmk (which uses pdflatex).  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156617/26911  For the non AUCTeX functions, the window (containing the compilation messages) only opens if there is an error.

Comment: In the event that you wish to write your own function, `start-process` has an option to create, **or** *not* create, the compilation output buffer.  However, the error messages (to the extent they exist) and/or compilation messages would be critical to debugging the `*.tex` file -- so another system for properly dealing with the compilation output would be advisable.  My guess is that you simply don't want to see the compilation output if everything generates successfully, which is different than completely suppressing the compilation output.